# how to catch spark exception and do something?

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

how to catch a exception and do something in catch block when I save data into hdfs fail. like this:

```
try {
    item.map(                    
       r => doSome(r).saveAsTextFiles(outputPath + "/data")
} catch {
      case e: Exception => {
      val failMessage = "Exception from output part" + e.getClass + "\t" + e.getMessage
      println("The exception is executed")
      update(aaa)
      }
} finally {
      mc.close()
}
```

I want to update some status when the save action throw exception. how to do it ?

Comment: Other than some typos that make this code fail to compile - what's wrong with it? If it doesn't produce the expected result - please show the expected vs. the actual result.

Comment: If I use a wrong port of hdfs master, it should throw exception and the catch block should be executed, but the result is that the exception is thrown, catch block can not be executed.

Comment: what do you mean "catch block can not be executed"? what do you see? Edit the question with these details.

Comment: I means the code in catch {} cannot be executed.

Comment: the result is code in catch {} cannot be executed

Comment: Well, your code works for me (after fixing compilation issues), and I still don't understand what you mean by "cannot be executed" - do you mean "_is_ not executed", as in - you don't see `The exception is executed` printed? Because I do. Plus, you create `failMessage` but don't use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use NonFatal hope it will solve your issue

```
import scala.util.control.NonFatal

try {
    item.map(                    
       r => doSome(r).saveAsTextFiles(outputPath + "/data")
} catch {
  case NonFatal(error) => {
     val failMessage = s"Exception from output part $error"
     println("The exception is executed")
     update(aaa)
  }
} finally {
      mc.close()
}
```

Comment: The item is s DStream, so the try catch is disable. I don't know the reason, but I can catch the exeption through item.foreachRdd{try{}catch{} }

Comment: In that case you should throw Exception either in doSome() function or in method of DStream saveAsTextFiles  by overriding it.